# Android Java ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android

I have some TextView which set the text from value saved in `SharedPreferences`. The values are split as array using "@".

```
SharedPreferences mark = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String savestock =  mark.getString("stock", null);
        if (savestock != null) {
            stock = savestock.split("@", -1);
            tvstrength.setText(stock[0]);
            tvavailable.setText(stock[1]);
            tvbrand.setText(stock[2]);
            tvbatch.setText(stock[3]);
            tvexp.setText(stock[4]);
            tvstrength2.setText(stock[5]);
            tvavailable2.setText(stock[6]);
            tvbrand2.setText(stock[7]);
            tvbatch2.setText(stock[8]);
            tvexp2.setText(stock[9]);
            }
```

This is how the `SharedPreferences` is saved:

```
SharedPreferences mark = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mark.edit();
editor.putString("stock", inStrength + "@" + inamt + "@" + inBrand + "@" + inBatch + "@" + inExp + 
inStrength2 + "@" + inamt2 + "@" + inBrand2 + "@" + inBatch2 + "@" + inExp2);
editor.commit();
```

However, I got the error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9`. The error is caused by `tvexp2.setText(stock[9]);`

What mistake I made?

Comment: your stock array probably has only 9 elements. Therefore stock[9] is out of bounds. print stock.length after the split

Comment: @Bentaye, but I have added 10 elements from `editor.putString`

Comment: still, print `savestock` and `stock` to make sure

Comment: you error is that you are adding 10 element in Array of 9 (length 9 , index 9 = element 10) you count from the 0 for the indexes and length from 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although, 9 string can be seen but according to your split expression you have 8 strings in your array. May be you have forgot to add **@ sysmbol** after string **inExp ** As it can seen **inExp + inStrength2 +** there is not @ symbol. Hope that helps you

Comment: There must be 9 strings in the array since the indices start from 0. Correct your math.

Comment: Thank you. What a silly mistake which cracked my head and using more than half and hour still unable to fix.

Comment: I am glad it helped you. Please mark my answer as accepted if that helped you :)

Comment: Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add one `"@"` symbol after `inExp` and before `inStrength2`. Here, I've fixed it for you:

```
SharedPreferences mark = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mark.edit();
editor.putString("stock", inStrength + "@" + inamt + "@" + inBrand + "@" + inBatch + "@" + inExp + "@" + inStrength2 + "@" + inamt2 + "@" + inBrand2 + "@" + inBatch2 + "@" + inExp2);
editor.commit();
```